# CRM 2015 - Reports Render on Server, but not when run locally (Same database, etc)

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, ssrs-2012, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

I have been wrestling this one for at least 24 hours, have extensively queried Google/Stack and other boards, and even asked an old colleague about this, but no one seems to have seen the issue before.

So I have a custom SSRS report built in Visual Studio.  The report will be running in CRM 2015 (On Prem).  When I run it directly from the server itself, the report loads, and all of the controls on the report render as well.  When I try to run the same report, on the same server, against the same records set, and on the same database, but I run it from my local machine (via IE, hit the CRM Web Site, and run the report), not only do no records load, but the report controls themselves do not load.  No messages are being displayed in Event Viewer or IIS logs that show me there is an issue.  I can simply not figure it out.

Any thoughts?

Here is a screen cap of the report when I run it from my local box, not the Server VM.  Notice that the controls are all greyed out, and there is nothing in the report body.

[image: Here is a screen cap of the report when I run it from my local box, not the Server VM.]

Comment: I should clarify - when I say 'run on the server' - I do not mean 'preview in VS' - I mean, add the report to a CRM solution, go into CRM, find the records I want to run it on, and then run the report.  From the server, it works perfectly.  If I follow the same exact steps, from my local machine browser, it fails miserably (as shown above).

My server is Win2012 and my local is Win10.  I am viewing the report in IE on both machines, as i only use IE for anything MS related due to many past trauma trying to use Chrome/FF to view SharePoint and CRM.

Comment: I'd suspect you are using a privileged user on your server. Did you try running your workstation IE under this user?

Comment: Not a bad idea.  However, my local machine does not belong to the domain that the server and the report lives on.

When I am logged into CRM, though, I am logged in using the same account I use to login to the server as well as login to CRM on the server.

Comment: In that case I'd recommend turning off auto-login to see what happens. Since you are hitting a custom report, you are authenticating against SSRS, not CRM. Domain Trust between your local machine and your SQL server could be another issue. Maybe also try browsing the SSRS ReportManager to see if you are denied any resources you'd expect to be able to access.

Comment: Is IE Enhanced Security Configuration turned off?

Comment: Yes IE Enhanced Security Config is turned off for Users and Admins at the server level.

I had a colleague go run the report, and it ran perfectly fine for him, and his machine is configured almost exactly as mine is (not on the domain of the servers, etc).

So, it seems to be a local config on my local machine, one which I cannot figure out at this time. But, the report runs perfectly fine for any other user who isn't me, and also runs fine from the client's perspective.

So I guess I will just ignore this error for the time being, and hope I can fix it later.